# Why does `bind -X` show inactive bindings?

Tags: bash, readline

When I bind a command using `bind -x` and then unbind it using `bind -r` it still shows up in the list of bindings `bind -X`.

1. Bind command using:

   ```
   bind -x "\"\C-r\":\"echo I just pressed C-R\""
   ```

   Everything works as expected.
   Pressing `\C-r` runs `echo I just pressed C-R`.
   Running `bind -X` shows the following list of bound commands:

   ```
   "\C-r": "echo I just pressed C-R"
   ```
2. Unbind command using

   ```
   bind -r "\C-r"
   ```

   Pressing `\C-r` does nothing as expected.
   Running `bind -X` still shows the same list of bound commands:

   ```
   "\C-r": "echo I just pressed C-R"
   ```

This behavior seems very weird to me. I would expect the binding list to match actual active bindings.

Bash version: `GNU bash, version 5.0.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)`

Comment: Hm, It get's unbinded [here](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/builtins/bind.def#L365) by calling `rl_bind_keyseq (seq, NULL)`. Get's printed from [here](https://github.com/bminor/bash/blob/master/bashline.c#L4286). Someone with understanding of [libreadline](https://github.com/issuu/readline/blob/master/bind.c#L424) would probably have to look at this. Wonder if this replicates across different bash versions and/or different libreadline versions.

Comment: @KamilCuk Could you try if it behaves the same way in your version of bash? I'm running bash 5.0.11

Comment: `bind -X` seems to be available up from bash:4.3. I tested with docker and could reproduce it with all bash:4.3 up to bash:5.